# Необходимо в tooltip отобразить картинку динамически созданного image, при чем image может быть сколько угодно

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Или же просто посоветуйте как в tooltip добавить image что бы туда изображение выводить через бихайнд

Comment: А зачем вам через code-behind? Почему не через привязку?

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашел, вот:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
StackPanel toolTipPanel = new StackPanel();
toolTipPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Картинка", FontSize=23 });
toolTipPanel.Children.Add(new Image { Source= Image[i].Source });
toolTip.Content = toolTipPanel;
button1.ToolTip = toolTip;
```